# Unexpected boldface with biblatex

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibtex

Unexpectedly I'm getting certain terms —"edition", "volume", "number", "editor", and "and" (the last for multiple authors) — when using `biblatex` with `bibtex` as the back end and with a custom biblatex style based upon `standard` and `numeric`.

The surprising thing is that this has happened only recently, suggesting that there has been some change in `bibtex`, `biblatex`, or the `standard` and `numeric` styles.

The `.tex` source:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\RequirePackage[strict=true]{csquotes}

\RequirePackage[backend=bibtex,%
    bibstyle=mybooknumeric,citestyle=numeric,dashed=true,defernumbers=true,
    urldate=edtf,date=edtf]%
    {biblatex} 

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{hyperindex,colorlinks, citecolor=red} 

\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
@book{Apostol1969vol2,
Author = {Apostol, Tom M.},
Edition = {2},
Maintitle = {Calculus},
Publisher = {Wiley},
Subtitle = {Multi-Variable Calculus and Linear Algebra with Applications to Differential Equations and Probability},
Title = {Calculus},
Volume = {2},
Year = {1969},
keywords={main}
}   
@Book{Bernays1991,
     title     = {Axiomatic Set Theory},
     publisher = {Dover},
     year      = {1991},
     author    = {Bernays, Paul},
     address   = {New York},
     edition   = {2},
     addendum  = {republication of 2 ed., North-Holland, 1958},
     location  = {New York},
     keywords={main}
}
@article{Archimedes200,
  author = {Archimedes},
  title = {Pi's the limit },
  journal = {Syracuse J. Gastronom.\ Math.}, 
  year = {200BCE},volume = {10},number={3},
  pages={\textsc{cccxv}--\textsc{cccxvii}},
  keywords={main}
}   
@article{EulerE1776,
    Author = {Euler, Leonhard},Title = {All about E},
    Journal = {Math.\ Psychol.},
    Year = {1776},Volume = {4},number={1},
    pages={1--2718},
    keywords={main}
  } 
@article{EulerE1748,
   Author = {Euler, Leonhard},Title = {My formula},
   Journal = {Math.\ Formulas},
   Year = {1748},Volume = {4},
   pages={233--234},
   keywords={main}
}
@book{CantorEmptySet1895,
editor = {Cantor, Georg},
title = {Eintausend und eins S\"{a}tze \"{u}ber die Nullmenge},
publisher = {Springer},
year = {1895},
location = {Berlin},
keywords = {main}
}
@book{BourbakiSets1970,
  Author = {Bourbaki, Nicolas},
  Title = {Th{\'e}orie des ensembles},
  Year ={ 1970},
  Publisher ={ Hermann},
  location ={ Paris},
  keywords = {two}
}    
@book{RussellWhitehead1927Vol3,
  author = {Whitehead, Alfred North and Russell, Bertrand},
  title = {Principia Mathematica},
  edition = {2},
  year = {1927},
  publisher = {Cambridge Univ.\ Press},
  volume = {3},
  keywords = {main}
}    
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{references.bib}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

The ``Alephs'' are discussed in \textcite[Section 26]{RussellWhitehead1927Vol3}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: Unexpected bolding in bibliography.]

Notice that the unexpected bolding of "and" in the entry with multiple authors also appears in the citation of that entry.

My `biblatex.cfg`:

```
% BIBLATEX.CFG
% mimic amsplain
\ProvidesFile{biblatex.cfg}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}

% Allow better line splits in URLs:
\Urlmuskip=0mu plus 1mu minus 1mu

% Punctuation & delimiter mods:
\DeclareLanguageMapping{english}{mylanguagestrings} % external file!
\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}
\renewcommand{\subtitlepunct}{\addcolon\addspace}
\renewbibmacro{in:}{%
  \ifentrytype{article}{}{\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}}

% Field mods:
\renewcommand*{\bibnamedash}{\rule{3em}{0.4pt}\hskip 0.16667em plus 0.01em minus 0.01em\relax \addcomma}
%
\renewbibmacro*{addendum+pubstate}{%
  \setunit{\addsemicolon\space}%
  \printfield{addendum}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{pubstate}}
%
\DeclareFieldFormat
  [article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]
  {title}{\mkbibemph{#1}}% no quote marks
  \DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{#1}
%
\DeclareFieldFormat
  [article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]
  {volume}{\mkbibbold{#1}}  
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}% no prefix for the `pages` field in the bibliography
%  
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}% no prefix for the `pages` field

% URL mods:    
\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\url{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\mkbibbrackets{\bibstring{urlseen}\space#1}}

% Book mods:    
\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
  \printlist{publisher}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \printlist{location}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit}

% Article mods:     
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{number}{\bibstring{number}~#1}% number of a journal

\renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
  \usebibmacro{journal}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\newunit
     \printfield{series}%
     \setunit{\addspace}}%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{issue+date}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\addcolon\space}%
  \usebibmacro{issue}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{eid}
  \newunit}
```

My custom `biblatex` style file, which is `~/Library/texmf/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/mybooknumeric.bbx`:

```
\ProvidesFile{mybooknumeric.bbx}
%
\RequireBibliographyStyle{standard}
\RequireBibliographyStyle{numeric}
%
\DeclareBibliographyOption[boolean]{dashed}[true]{%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{true}
    {\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{pagetracker}%
     \renewbibmacro*{bbx:savehash}{\savefield{fullhash}{\bbx@lasthash}}}
    {\renewbibmacro*{bbx:savehash}{}}}
%
\newbibmacro*{bbx:savehash}{%
  \savefield{fullhash}{\bbx@lasthash}}

\renewbibmacro*{author}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test \ifuseauthor
    and
    not test {\ifnameundef{author}}
  }
  {\usebibmacro{bbx:dashcheck}
    {\bibnamedash}
    {\printnames{author}%
      \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
      \usebibmacro{bbx:savehash}}%
    \usebibmacro{authorstrg}}
  {\global\undef\bbx@lasthash}}

\newbibmacro*{bbx:dashcheck}[2]{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\iffieldequals{fullhash}{\bbx@lasthash}}
    and
    not test \iffirstonpage
  }
  {#1}
  {#2}}
```

And a custom `mylanguagestrings.lbx`, which is in my local texmf tree as `~/Library/texmf/tex/biblatex/lbx/mylanguagestrings.lbx` (I'm not sure this gets used):

```
\ProvidesFile{custom-english-ordinal-sscript.lbx}
%
\InheritBibliographyExtras{english}
%
\DeclareBibliographyExtras{%
  \protected\def\mkbibordinal#1{%
\begingroup%
 \@tempcnta0#1\relax\number\@tempcnta%%
    \endgroup}%
  \protected\def\mkbibmascord{\mkbibordinal}%
  \protected\def\mkbibfemord{\mkbibordinal}%
}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  urlseen =    {accessed},
}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{american}{%
  urlseen =    {accessed},
}
\endinput
```

Comment: Those are strings which biblatex has not found. You should include an `inherit = {english},` in your `\DefineBibliographyStrings` statement (also for american).

Comment: Actually, more precisely, as you are in your own `.lbx`, you should use `\DeclareBibliographyStrings` instead of `\DefineBibliographyStrings` (care for the different syntax).

Comment: Sorry, I don't fully understand. In the custom `.lbx` I changed `\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{urlseen =    {accessed},}` to `\DeclareBibliographyStrings{inherit = {english},urlseen =    {accessed},}` and similarly for `american`. But now when tex'ing the source, I get a `Missing \begin{document}` when it gets to the end of the first `DeclareBibliographyStrings` command in the `.lbx`. Are there some additional changes needed in the source, in the custom `.bbx`, or in `biblatex.cfg` now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Biblatex renders the string name (the internal one) bold, when it can't find the string's value. As the string names are somewhat similar to the `english` values, it is harder to understand what's going on in this case. Anyway, it means the values for the strings weren't found by biblatex.

In your case, the problem is that you are using a personal `.lbx` file, associated with the language english in your `\DeclareLanguageMapping{english}{mylanguagestrings}` but using preamble syntax to redefine some strings.

So, you should use instead:

```
\DeclareBibliographyStrings{%
  inherit = {english},
  urlseen = {{accessed}{accessed}},
}
```

This inherits the strings from biblatex's `english.lbx` and (re)define the following ones. Notice we don't add the language here, which is defined by the language mapping (thus `english`). Also, contrary to the syntax of `DefineBibliographyStrings`, with `DeclareBibliographyStrings` you must provide both long and abbreviated forms of the string.

So, you could have your `mylanguagestrings.lbx` as:

```
\ProvidesFile{mylanguagestrings.lbx}
% with custom-english-ordinal-sscript
%
\InheritBibliographyExtras{english}
%
\DeclareBibliographyExtras{%
  \protected\def\mkbibordinal#1{%
\begingroup%
 \@tempcnta0#1\relax\number\@tempcnta%%
    \endgroup}%
  \protected\def\mkbibmascord{\mkbibordinal}%
  \protected\def\mkbibfemord{\mkbibordinal}%
}

\DeclareBibliographyStrings{%
  inherit = {english},
  urlseen = {{accessed}{accessed}},
}

\endinput
```

Off-topic: your code issues plenty of deprecated commands warnings, you should look at those.

Comment: Got it! - thank you!  I had already noticed the `biblatex`"deprecated" warnings, and I have now replaced`urldate` and `date` values of`edtf `with `iso` and added `seconds=true`, so as to avoid those warnings.

Comment: @murray, you should also consider using the `biber` backend, the `bibtex` one is considered legacy, and does not support the full feature set of biblatex/biber.

Comment: I just switched from `bibtex` to `biber`, and all is well -- except that I had to add `\setcounter{biburllcpenalty}{7000}` and `\setcounter{biburlucpenalty}{8000}` in place of a forced insertion of `{\,}` for a very long URL in my `.bib` source.